# Applying absorption law in set theory

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

[image]

I'm solving part C in particular (specifically $P[C\cap D^C]$).

Here is the solution the textbook gives:

[image]

However, it appears to be incorrect. This is how I solved it:

\begin{align}
P[C\cap D^C] & = P[C\cap (A\cup B\cup C)]\\[8pt]
& = P[C]\quad \text{(by absorption law)} \\[8pt]
& =\frac 5 8
\end{align}

I just want some clarification that I didn't make a mistake and that it's just a textbook error.

Comment: How do you get from $D^\complement$ to $A\cup B\cup C$? The problem does not say that the four events partition the sample space. (On the _contrary_, it is specified that $C$ and $D$ are independent, which requires them to have nonempty intersection).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ah, thank you. It seems I've made an incorrect assumption.

Comment: Intuitively, if $C$ and $D$ are independent, so are $C$ and $D^c$ (and $C^c$  and $D^c$). To show this more formally: $P(C)=P(C\cap D)+P(C\cap D^c)=P(C)P(D)+P(C\cap D^c)$ hence $P(C\cap D^c)=P(C)(1-P(D))=P(C)P(D^c)$.